# Is it advisable to use mutable operations for array in mobx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

Every time in `react` I care about `immutable array operations`
to avoid accidental state changes via `mutable operations`

I often use `immutable operations`

whenever I need to add a new item I use this

```js
[...myArr, 'newItem'];
```

instead of mutable oprations

```js
myArr.push('newItem');
```

However, I saw an example of `mobx` on the [official doc](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started), And I was surprised because they use `push()` method.

I am a beginner in `mobx`, and I am afraid to use `mutable operation`,
Does anyone have an idea about it?

am I doing wrong or Can I go with a `mutable` operation on `mobx` with react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operations have different semantics and consequences, everything depends on what your goal is.

Do you need to notify all observables that this array changed? Then create new array, like that `[...myArr, 'newItem'];` or any other way you prefer.

Do you just need to add an item to array? Use `push`

For example, every `useEffect` that has deps for that array will react in the first case, but there will be no effect in the second case when you `push`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ...
}, [myArray])
```

Comment: You mean I can use anyone depends on the situation? but trust me I saw many posts of `react` where they restrict to use of these mutable methods `push()` `splice()`

Comment: Yes, you can use both with MobX. React actually does not have observers and reactive data so if you use pure React state it might be better to stick with immutable approach.

Comment: Thanks, You saved my brain to be messed :)

Comment: @HidaytRahman please mark some answer as accepted if your question was resolved, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Spread operator with ... create a new array, that needs to allocate some memory. So, it kind of costly in comparison to `push`

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [...arr]; // like arr.slice()

arr2.push(4);
//  arr2 becomes [1, 2, 3, 4]
//  arr remains unaffected
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: oh that's great to use, can be combined with spread.. thanks!